# YouTube Upload Widget / OnStateChange event listener

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to use the onStateChange event listener for the YouTube upload widget to call another function depending on the upload widget's state, but I can't seem to get the onStateChange event listener to work with the upload widget. See my code below. Oddly, when I use the same technique to add an onStateChange listener for an iframe player alone, it works just fine. Anyone have any bright ideas? Or is the upload widget api just buggy?

```
<script>    
var player;
var widget;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
    events: {

      }
                       }
                       );

 widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onWidgetStateChange,
        'onUploadSuccess': onUploadSuccess,
        'onProcessingComplete': onProcessingComplete
      }
    });
  }

function onWidgetStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.UploadWidgetState.RECORDING) {
      player1.playVideo();
              }
}

function onUploadSuccess(event) {
    alert('Video ID ' + event.data.videoId + ' was uploaded and is currently being       processed.');
  }

function onProcessingComplete(event) {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: 390,
      width: 640,
      videoId: event.data.videoId,
      events: {

          }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you need to change `event.data == YT.UploadWidgetState.RECORDING` to `event.data.state == YT.UploadWidgetState.RECORDING`

When making that change, I was able to put together a jsfiddle that pretty much does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffposnick/yhWsG/35/